# How to find $\lim\limits_{x \to0 } \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^2}$? L'Hopital's rule doesn't work.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to determine the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to0 } \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^2}
$$

I tried using l'Hopital's rule but $\frac{0}{0}$ uncertainty didn't change. Also a degree of function increased.
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to0 } \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^4}
$$

If I'll use l'Hopital's rule again $\frac{0}{0}$ uncertainty will stay.
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to0 } \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{2x^6}
$$
I guess I need other thoughts.

Comment: Put $y=\frac 1{x^{2}}$ and then apply L'Hopital's Rule. ($e^{-y}=\frac 1 {e^{y}}$)

Comment: Uh, maybe you did the right job. The value of $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}}{x^2}$ is $0$, and as same as $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}}{x^4}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm as y goes inf ? And $\lim\limits_{y \to inf } \frac{y}{e^y} = \lim\limits_{y \to inf } \frac{1}{e^y} = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, $y\to +\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use L'Hospital's Rule, here is one way forward.  Note that $\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}=\frac{1/x^2}{e^{1/x^2}}$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{1/x^2}=\infty$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1/x^2}{e^{1/x^2}}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{LHR}\frac{(-2/x^3)}{(-2/x^3)e^{1/x^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: (+1) With a change of point of view ($u=1/x^2$) the problems becomes a little easier: $\frac{u}{e^u}\sim\frac{1}{e^u}\xrightarrow{u\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Answer (score 1):

Try the arithmetic with a variable switching method :

Let  y := $1/x^2$

any devolved to : $$x\;\to\;0\;\;\implies\;y\;\to\;＋\infty$$
because : $x^2 > 0 $

We get :
$$\underset{y\rightarrow＋\infty}{\lim} \;ye^{-y}＝\underset{y\rightarrow＋\infty}{\lim} \;\frac {y}{e^y}＝0$$

So :
$$\underset{x\rightarrow\;0}{\lim}\;\frac {e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}}{x^2}＝0$$